# P/Invoke Marshalling an Out void*

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have the following C function definition:

```
EXPORT CreateWindow(const wchar_t* applicationTitle, void* windowHandle) {
    // Some preconditions & other stuff here

    windowHandle = RENDER_COMPONENT.Window.CreateNew(cstr_to_wstring(applicationTitle));
    return true;
}
```

The function is called via P/Invoke. The P/Invoke function definition is as follows:

```
[DllImport(InteropUtils.RUNTIME_DLL, EntryPoint = "CreateWindow", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern bool _CreateWindow([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string applicationTitle, [Out] out IntPtr windowHandle);
```

The usage of this function is:

```
IntPtr windowHandle;
bool windowCreationSuccess = _CreateWindow(Engine.ApplicationTitle, out windowHandle);
```

---

My problem is that `windowHandle` is always equal to IntPtr.Zero in the C# code, which I guess means that it isn't being 'copied' from the C++ to C# side somehow. It is being set in the C function (I looked with the debugger)- it is actually a HWND.

P/Invoke never ceases to confuse me - I'm sure I've done something wrong with copying a struct rather than a reference to it or something, but I can't quite see what/where.

Comment: is this a completely different method than the CreateWindowEx in user32? http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/CreateWindowEx.html

Comment: The C code is broken, it cannot work correctly either when you call it from a C program.  The correct argument declaration is `HWND*`, prettier than `void**`.  Always unit-test C code before you try to pinvoke it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C uses pass by value exclusively. This means that your assignment to `windowHandle` can never be seen by the caller. That is so for any caller, not just a managed pinvoke.

You need to change the C function to receive the address of the window handle variable. Like this:

```
EXPORT CreateWindow(const wchar_t* applicationTitle, HWND* windowHandle) {
    // Some preconditions & other stuff here
    *windowHandle = RENDER_COMPONENT.Window.CreateNew(cstr_to_wstring(applicationTitle));
    return true;
}
```

The C# code in the question then matches.

However your C code is odd. Why do you return true unconditionally? Why bother returning a bool if it is always true. Frankly it would be cleaner to return the HWND.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To address your comments: The return value is not always true, some of the precondition stuff I omitted for brevity could return false. Also it just follows a general pattern I've being using for P/Invoke calls. Also I'm trying to keep this interface platform-agnostic, hence the void* (not HWND).